# What are the simplest known algorithms to compute PI?

Tags: complexity-theory, lambda-calculus, discrete-mathematics, kolmogorov-complexity

There are many algorithms that compute PI. Some are obviously complex, involving huge formulas and constants. Some formulas are not that complex, but involve operators such as `division` which is somewhat complex by itself. Is there any algorithm that is inherently simple and could be expressed very tightly on the untyped lambda calculus?

Comment: Nothing to do with Pi will be simple in the untyped lambda calculus, since you're going to need to Church encode integers, then encode floating point values using integers.

Comment: Maybe there is another representation of real numbers which is natural enough to be acceptable, isn't as complex as floating point arithmetic, and allows for a short definition of `Pi`. That is what I'm looking for. In worst case, no need for church-naturals; you can just encode the usual floating point arithmetic operations on the λ-calculus. That will cost a bytes, though.

Comment: If you haven't seen it already, you may find [Jeremy Gibbon's paper on streaming spigot algorithms](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/spigot.pdf) for $\pi$ interesting. The stream of digits could arguably be viewed as a representation for (computable) reals. They do use integer division.  You may also find [Bill Gosper's classic algorithms for doing arithmetic on continued fractions](http://perl.plover.com/yak/cftalk/INFO/gosper.txt) (another, better behaved, representation of computable reals) interesting.

Comment: Hey, very interesting. If continued fractions are better behaved, why cauchy sequences are all that I hear about?

Comment: @DerekElkins I love the continued fractions paper!!!! Thank you!!!!!

Comment: What about `4 * (1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9 ...)`? Seems simple enough and you can calculate to any precision you want. Ah, sorry, I missed the "no division" requirement.